# Only one BroadcastReceiver allowed to receive billing broadcasts for Android in-app billing?

Tags: android, manifest, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, billing

I have gotten Google's sample in-app billing app (Dungeons) working just fine. However, I'm trying to register a second billing receiver for an app I'm writing, and I'm unable to do so. It seems as though only the first receiver declared in my AndroidManifest.xml is the one that receives broadcasts, but any following the first one do not receive broadcasts. At run-time, I've confirmed that the broadcast is not an ordered broadcast by using isOrderedBroadcast(), so it's not as though I'm aborting the broadcast somewhere (only ordered broadcasts can be aborted). Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the first receiver needs to be unregistered before the second one can do what it is trying to do. In your activity, override the onStop() method so that the broadcast receiver is unregistered when the activity closes. This is what has worked for me.

```
// Import statements go here.

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IabBroadcastReceiver.IabBroadcastListener {

    // Other variables and methods go here.

    // Unregister the receiver when the activity closes.
    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(YOUR_BROADCAST_RECEIVER_VARIABLE_NAME_HERE);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Uncomment the following for debugging.
            //ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Call the original onStop() method.
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```